# Sorting a varchar column in customized way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sort a varchar column A which contains the data like this:

```
A.1)    NULL
A.1.xc) 1131820
B.1)    NULL
B.1.xc) 1131822
C.1)    NULL
C.1.xc) 131824
C.2) (CE)   NULL
C.2) (NRML) NULL
C.2.xc) 131826
C.2.xc) 132152
C.3)    NULL
C.3.a)  131828
C.3.a.xc)   131830
C.3.xc) 131828
C.4)    NULL
C.4.a)  131838
C.4.a.xc)   131840
C.4.xc) 131838
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1)    NULL
D.1.xc) 16131842
D.1.xc) 15131842
D.1.xc) 14131842
D.1.xc) 13131842
D.1.xc) 12131842
D.1.xc) 11131842
D.1.xc) 10131842
D.1.xc) 9131842
D.1.xc) 8131842
D.1.xc) 7131842
D.1.xc) 6131842
D.1.xc) 5131842
D.1.xc) 4131842
D.1.xc) 1131842
D.1.xc) 3131842
D.1.xc) 2131842
D.2)    NULL
D.2.xc) 132124
D.3)    NULL
D.3.xc) 132126
D.4)    NULL
D.4.xc) 1132156
D.5) (NRML) NULL
D.5.xc) 132158
E.1)    NULL
E.1.xc) 132138
E.10)   NULL
E.10.xc)    131932
E.10.xf)    131932
E.10.xl)    131932
E.11) (NRML)    NULL
E.11.xc)    131939
E.11.xf)    131939
E.11.xl 131939
E.12.a) NULL
E.12.a.xc)  131965
E.12.a.xl)  131965
E.13)   NULL
E.13.a) 131988
E.13.a.xc)  131990
E.13.xc)    131988
E.14)   NULL
E.14.xc)    131994
E.14.xl)    131994
E.15)   NULL
E.15.xc)    132012
E.16)   NULL
E.16.xc)    132014
E.17.a) (ALLFNDS)   NULL
E.17.a.xc)  132016
E.17.a.xf)  132016
E.18)   NULL
E.18.xc)    132022
E.2)    NULL
E.2.xc) 131844
E.3)    NULL
E.3.xc) 131850
E.4)    NULL
E.4.xc) 131856
E.5)    NULL
E.5.xc) 131862
E.6)    NULL
E.6.xc) 131868
E.7)    NULL
E.7.a)  131874
E.7.a.xc)   131876
E.7.b)  131874
E.7.b.i)    131878
E.7.b.i.xc) 131886
E.7.b.xc)   131878
E.7.xc) 131874
E.8) (NRML) NULL
E.8.xc) 131890
E.9) (NRML) NULL
E.9.a)  131908
E.9.a.xc)   131910
E.9.a.xf)   131910
E.9.a.xl)   131910
E.9.xc) 131908
```

I am using below query to sort the column

```
Select A,Bfrom ABCD where id =18613
order by A
```

Now this query is giving me the issue that E.1.xc), I am expecting E.2) but it is returning me E.10) and so on.

Column A is a varchar column.

I also tried this query but with no luck

```
SELECT 

CASE 
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(A)=1 
  THEN CAST(A as int)

  WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',A) > 1 
  THEN CAST(
    LEFT(
      A,
      PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',A) - 1
    ) as int)

  ELSE 2147483648
END, 


CASE 
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(A)=1 
  THEN NULL

  WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',A) > 1 
  THEN SUBSTRING(
      A,
      PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',A) ,
      50
    ) 

  ELSE A
END
from ABCD where id=18613 order by A
```

Also to note that like after D.5) which contains theB as NULL I wan its sub branch as D.5 xc) having its B column as 132158.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa929/1)

Comment: You must post table definition. Also, you wrote: sorting problem, but from description it does not seems a sorting problem. More a selection problem.

Comment: please post the table structure

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question that the column A is a varchar. What else do you want for table definition?

Comment: Your second query doesn't have an order by clause.

Comment: @DanBracuk:- Yes, but even if I add that then also I am facing the issue with E10 coming before E2

Comment: But you are still ordering by a, not the results of your case constructs.

Comment: @DanBracuk:- Yes, I know I am missing something. Could you suggest me where I missed?

Comment: @DanBracuk:- I have added a Sql fiddle which I am trying now. If you see after A1, A2 is expected but it is not working. It is coming as A10

Comment: Use a numeric-sensitive collation in the order by. (If SQL Server has that functionality... I don't know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
It uses the PARSENAME function is sql which is actually to split an object name into it's various parts, but will split anything with dots...

```
SELECT A, B
FROM (
    SELECT A, B, 
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(A) - LEN(REPLACE(A, '.', '')) = 3 THEN A
        WHEN PATINDEX('%.', REPLACE(A, ')', '.')) > 0 THEN REPLACE(A, ')', '.') + 'x'
        ELSE REPLACE(A, ')', '.')
    END as dummy
    FROM ABCD) data
    ORDER BY LEFT(data.A, 1), 
    CONVERT(INT, CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(data.dummy, 4)) = 1 THEN PARSENAME(data.dummy, 4)
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(data.dummy, 3)) = 1 THEN PARSENAME(data.dummy, 3)
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(data.dummy, 2)) = 1 THEN PARSENAME(data.dummy, 2)
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(data.dummy, 1)) = 1 THEN PARSENAME(data.dummy, 1)
    END), data.A
```

This query might not cater for all the permutations in your data, but it's a start.
You get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1: Split your sort criterion**

Use the SQL Server string manipulation and casting methods to add the following fields to your result set:

```
Major (varchar)   Minor (int)   Remainder    yourOtherFields
-------------------------------------------------------------
   A                  1            NULL           ...
   A                  1            xc             ...
...
```

(For example, Minor can be extracted by getting the substring between the first `.` and the following `.` or `)` and casting it to integer.)

**Step 2: Sort**

```
SELECT myField1, myField2, ...
  FROM (...SQL from Step 1...) AS mySource
 ORDER BY Major, Minor, Remainder
```

This ensures a string sort order on Major and Remainder, but an integer sort order on Minor.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But can you fix my query(if possible)?

Comment: @RameshKulkarni that is basic string manipulation in SQL. you can do it for yourself. Lookup sql functions indexof and substring and use them.

Comment: @AdrianNasui:- I have tried and I am puzzled now. Getting nowhere so thought to ask with the attempt which I made. This is my first question here, so no idead about the rules. Sorry

Comment: @Heinzi:- I have added a Sql fiddle which I am trying now. If you see after A1, A2 is expected but it is not working. It is coming as A10

Comment: @RameshKulkarni: I suggest that you don't try to do both steps at once. Concentrate on step 1 first (split your field), *then* worry about sorting your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try with your suggstion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy. Not very elegant, but it should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM ABCD
ORDER BY 
LEFT(A,CHARINDEX('.',A,1)-1), 
CAST(
LEFT( 
    RIGHT(A,LEN(A)-CHARINDEX('.',A,1)), 
    ISNULL( 
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',RIGHT(A,LEN(A)-CHARINDEX('.',A,1)),1),0), 
               CHARINDEX(')',RIGHT(A,LEN(A)-CHARINDEX('.',A,1)),1) 
           )
    -1
    )
AS INT)
```